# Why is kFlurryEventFailed ? (Android / Flurry)

Tags: flurry

Why is kFlurryEventFailed ?

```
    // app analytics flurry
    new FlurryAgent.Builder()
            .withLogEnabled(false)
            .build(this, getString(R.string.flurryID));
    FlurryEventRecordStatus a = FlurryAgent.logEvent("App Start.");
```

"a" is "kFlurryEventFailed". Why???

```
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Flurry Analytics got a log.But Flurry event is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is likely failing because it is invoked immediately after the call to start the Flurry session. You can use a session listener in this instance to resolve this:

```
new FlurryAgent.Builder()
            .withLogEnabled(true)
            .withListener(new FlurryAgentListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSessionStarted() {

                   // your session handling code 
                   FlurryEventRecordStatus a = FlurryAgent.logEvent("App Start.");
                }

            })
            .build(this, R.string.flurryID);
```

Also note you are using an older sdk version. Check the integration guide here:
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/

```
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.0.2@aar'
```